# Cannot login from TTY: Auto \r when TTY login

Tags: greeter

When I use Linux Console (tty1-6) to login, I type my username then press Enter, then it auto return. It make me cannot login from tty.

The [video on Vimeo](https://vimeo.com/320996187)

I have check the log from `journalctl | grep login`. The log file on [Gist](https://gist.github.com/lancatlin/59eb5dc15de5b53657a894b1bb8298c9)

I meet this problem not only on my laptop but also on my PC, but it's fine on Arch Linux on my laptop, so I think it's not Linux kernal's problem.

My hardware information is also put on [Gist](https://gist.github.com/lancatlin/59eb5dc15de5b53657a894b1bb8298c9).

Thanks for help.

Comment: I also have this problem. Funny thing is it was okay last time I checked. But when I checked just a while ago it didn't work. I have already created an issue on github. I think its related to some recent updates.